# How to SSH into a parallels centos 7 VM, ip a command does not have ip?

Tags: linux

I'm trying to setup ssh for centos as a linux newb.

When I run ip a,  i have  1:lo, loopback 127.0.01 and 2: eth0.  eth0 has a mac address but no ip.

How do I configure the ip?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the virtual Parallels network is handling DHCP, if not you will need to configure a static IP before you can access the box over SSH.

You can try to retrieve an IP using `dhclient eth0` don't forget to run the command as root or by using sudo.

If you need to statically configure an IP you can do so by using the `ip` command. For example, to add an IP of 192.168.0.2 on eth0 you would run: `sudo ip addr add 192.168.0.2/24 dev eth0`

You can find some more "ip" commands here: https://access.redhat.com/sites/default/files/attachments/rh_ip_command_cheatsheet_1214_jcs_print.pdf or the man page: https://linux.die.net/man/8/ip

Answer (score 0):

You need to bridge the connection between your mac and linux

http://kb.parallels.com/ca/4948

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try nmcli

```
Nmcli device connect eth0
```

Should do it